# Erro ao criar um método numa aplicação WFA em herança e polimorfismo

Tags: c#, herança, polimorfismo

Criei um projeto WFA que servirá de base para os demais, segue a descrição:

1. Criei um FormBase que tem variáveis públicas de controle, como o nome do operador, data e hora de acesso ao sistemas;
2. Criei um FormBasePrincipal, que instancia FormBase, colocando neste um menu, barra de estatus, barra de ferramentas;
3. Criei um FormBaseConsulta, que instancia FormBase, neste coloquei uma barra de ferramentas, um DataGridView , instanciei uma classe DAL que criei para conectar ao banco de dados (postgres, a princípio).

Até aqui tudo funciona legal.

Minha dificuldade é na classe FormBaseConsulta que tenho um método para obter a string do SQL conforme segue:

```
    public virtual string getSCriptConsulta()
    {
        sScriprtSQL = "";

        return sScriprtSQL;
    }
```

Na classe FormComEstados, que instancia FormBaseConsulta tem uma classe que define o SQL:

```
    public override string getSCriptConsulta() 
    {
        return "select ufcodigo as codigo, " +
               "       ufsigla as uf, " +
               "       ufnome as estado " +
               "from cadastros.tbestados " +
               "order by ufnome ";
    }
```

Está funcionando tudo direitinho, trazendo a lista dos estados, porém quero alterar algumas propriedades das colunas, para isto criei uma classe conforme segue:

```
namespace wfaPraticandoHeranca
{
    class EntidadeGridColumns
    {
        private string sFieldName = null;
        private string sHeaderText = null;
        private int iMinimumWidth = 0;
        private string sToolTipText = null;
        private int iWidth = 0;
        private bool bFroze = false;

        public string FieldName
        {
            get { return sFieldName; }
            set { sFieldName = value; }
        }

        public string HeaderText
        {
            get { return sHeaderText; }
            set { sHeaderText = value; }
        }

        public int MinimumWidth
        {
            get { return iMinimumWidth; }
            set { iMinimumWidth = value; }
        }

        public string ToolTipText
        {
            get { return sToolTipText; }
            set { sToolTipText = value; }
        }

        public int Width
        {
            get { return iWidth; }
            set { iWidth = value; }
        }

        public bool Frozen
        {
            get { return bFroze; }
            set { bFroze = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

No FormBaseConsulta criei uma classe conforme segue:

```
    public virtual EntidadeGridColumns getGridColumnsProperties()
    {
        EntidadeGridColumns colProperties = new EntidadeGridColumns[0];

        return colProperties;
    }
```

Esta classe está me reportando o erro (com `getGridColumnsProperties()` sublinhado em azul):

> Error 3  Inconsistent accessibility: return type
>   'wfaPraticandoHeranca.EntidadeGridColumns' is less accessible than
>   method
>   'wfaPraticandoHeranca.frmModeloConsultas.getGridColumnsProperties()'

No FormConEstados eu sobrescrevi a classe:

```
    public override EntidadeGridColumns setColumnsProperties()
    {
        EntidadeGridColumns colProperties = new EntidadeGridColumns[3];

        colProperties[0] = new EntidadeGridColumns();
        colProperties[0].FieldName = "codigo";
        colProperties[0].HeaderText = "Código";
        colProperties[0].MinimumWidth = 75;
        colProperties[0].Width = 75;
        colProperties[0].ToolTipText = "Código do cadastro do Estado...";
        colProperties[0].Frozen = true;

        colProperties[1] = new EntidadeGridColumns();
        colProperties[1].FieldName = "sigla";
        colProperties[1].HeaderText = "Sigla";
        colProperties[1].MinimumWidth = 60;
        colProperties[1].Width = 60;
        colProperties[1].ToolTipText = "UF do Estado...";
        colProperties[1].Frozen = false;

        colProperties[2] = new EntidadeGridColumns();
        colProperties[2].FieldName = "estado";
        colProperties[2].HeaderText = "Estado";
        colProperties[2].MinimumWidth = 250;
        colProperties[2].Width = 25;
        colProperties[2].ToolTipText = "Nme do Estado...";
        colProperties[2].Frozen = false;

        return colProperties;

    }
```

Esta classe está me reportando o erro (com "getGridColumnsProperties()" sublinhado em azul):

> Error 2  Inconsistent accessibility: return type
>   'wfaPraticandoHeranca.EntidadeGridColumns' is less accessible than
>   method 'wfaPraticandoHeranca.frmConEstados.setColumnsProperties()'

Em fim, estes são os erros que estou tendo, se puderem me ajudar serei grato, pois não tenho ideia de como resolver isto!

Ao meu ver a classe `EntidadeGridColumns` não pode ser utilizada como retorno do método e não sei tenho ideia de como fazer em C#.

Nota:
  - Outro erro que está acontecendo, visto que estes sção os erro 2 e 3, o design do FormConEstados não abre mais reportando o erro:

```
> Connection string argument missing! Parameter name: Host

Mas executando tudo funciona devidamente; já excluí as pastas BIN e OBJ mas não deu certo. Já verifiquei no "Npgsql" este parâmetro "Host" e não encontre nada, apenas "Server".
```

Perdoem-me, nem sei como definir o Título pra esta situação.

Comment: Altere `class EntidadeGridColumns` para `public class EntidadeGridColumns`